# Camera move with my character

Tags: swift, camera, sprite-kit, character

I have this little project I'm working on, and I'm a complete beginner. I need some help how I could implement a working camera that would follow the "char" around. Thanks in advance.

If you could point me in the right direction, as to where I add the code. That would be terrific, since I looked over some tutorials, and didnt really know as to where to put some of the code.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {


var char = SKSpriteNode()
var bg = SKSpriteNode()
var platform = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    var bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img/bg.png")
    bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
    bg.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    bg.size.height = self.frame.height

    self.addChild(bg)

    var charTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img/char.png")

    char = SKSpriteNode(texture: charTexture)
    char.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: 900)

    char.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: char.size.height / 2)
    char.physicsBody!.dynamic = true

    self.addChild(char)

    var platformTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img/platform.png")

    platform = SKSpriteNode(texture: platformTexture)
    platform.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    platform.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform.size)
    platform.physicsBody!.dynamic = false

    self.addChild(platform)


    var wall = SKNode()
    wall.position = CGPointMake(0,0)
    wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(1, self.frame.size.height))
    wall.physicsBody!.dynamic = false

    self.addChild(wall)

    var ground = SKNode()
    ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 1))
    ground.physicsBody!.dynamic = false

    self.addChild(ground)



}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    char.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0)
    char.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(3, 0))

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

Comment: That is for obj-C, im doing this in swift

Comment: http://swiftalicio.us/2014/09/2d-camera-in-spritekit/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make camera follow the player in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302168/how-to-make-camera-follow-the-player-in-swift)